# Setting value for control attributes with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, attributes

I'm new to Spring and Spring MVC. I developed some web-apps in **ASP.NET** and the different approach followed by this framework is confusing me a bit.

Now I'm trying to develop a sample application and I need to change the text of some controls (buttons, labels, etc.).

For example: I have a button that starts/stops a data extraction process. I'd like to set the text of the button to "START" and then when I click it (and the process is started), I'd like to set the button text to "STOP". Similar changes should be done for several labels.

In ASP.NET I simply set the `Text` property of each control.

How can I achieve this with Spring MVC, from a controller?

**NOTE**
This also applies to every control attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameters to the returned model. For example:

```
 //some other controller code
 @RequestMapping("/start")
 public ModelAndView start(....) {
       ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("example");
       mav.addObject("button_text", "START");

       return mav;
 }
 //...
```

then, in your example.jsp:

```
<input type="button" value="${button_text}" />
```

Still, it looks like you're trying to implement ideas taken from component-based framework using an action-response one, which might not be the best idea.

Comment: I come from ASP.NET, so maybe you're right when you say: _"it looks like you're trying to implement component-based navigation using action-response"_. So, which approach should I follow? Is my question incorrect?

Comment: @daviooh if you can still change the framework, you'd probably feel more at home with JSF (although it's a good idea to learn spring). If you can't do that then try not to think in terms of components. In spring you have views (usually jsp, which are only a small step up from pure html), controllers (which react to actions from views, usually form submits and ajax stuff) and models (the data you send back from controller to view). It's all loosely coupled in spring. There's no 1-to-1 mapping from html elements to controllers/model elements.

Comment: So instead of putting a label in the model (labels are IMO something your controller shouldn't worry about), send a boolean indicating if it's started or not, and decide what label to show in the view, based on the value of that boolean. But it really depends on personal taste.

Comment: Perfect! I'm studying this framework because I know its potentialities. I don't want to change it, I'd just like to learn the right "way of thinking" to use it correctly. So if i'm not wrong, you are saying to set the text (or other attributes) using javascript, right?

Comment: You can set them in controller, there's just no concept of 'control attributes' here at least not in asp.net sense. There's no control on the server side where you can set the text and have it displayed on the client side. You just send the data and receive responses. Probably doing some stuff on the client to limit client-server communication is a good idea, but you're not forced to do that.

Comment: Maybe I'm not using the right term when I say "control attribute". I mean also an HTML element (`div`, `span`, `input`, etc.) attribute. So, thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pro myself but the way I do it is with javascript.

Some code would be something like

```
function changeText() {
   var button = document.getElementById("yourButtonId"); // same as the id attribute of the button
   button.value = "STOP"; 
}
```

And then in the jsp code you could have:

```
<input type="button" name="someName" value="START" onclick="changeText()"/>
```

I think that could work.

Later edit: i see you asked specifically how to do it from the controller, which means from Java code, sorry if my answer isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'd like to know if it is possible to set attributes value directly from the code. If not, I'll follow your approach...